# Deploy Compodoc documentation on GitLab without using GitLab Pages

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci, compodoc

Dear fellow developers,

I'd like to deploy our `Compodoc` documentation to `GitLab` in order to make it available to every developer within our team (like an API page).

According to the company I'm working for, I can't use `GitLab` Pages for this.

Any ideas?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is probably more suited to be posted in the [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do you have answer of this question?

Comment: I do, see my reply for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The company I am working for does not allow GitLab pages for some reason. So I had to come up with another solution.

> Please keep in mind that I was looking for a way to make the
>   documentation accessible to every developer.

In order to do so, I basically had to make two steps:

1. Modify `package.json`

   `"docgen": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json",`

   `"doc:buildandserve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -s",`

   `"bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"`

   This will build and serve the documentation wherever it
   is deployed.
2. Modify build pipeline

   I had to insert an extra step within my pipe to execute the above code so that developers can access the documentation like  `http:\\www.your-applications-url.com\documentation`

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the use of "bundle-report" task here?